# Unable to assign Qt3DCore::Quick::Quick3DEntity to QQmlComponent

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

Trying to add a delegate-like property to a custom Qt3D entity:

MyEntity.qml:

```
Entity {
    id: root
    default property Entity delegate // <-- MyEntity.qml:26
    property int n: 1
    property matrix4x4 t

    NodeInstantiator {
        id: rep
        model: root.n
        delegate: Entity {
            components: [
                Transform {
                    matrix: {
                        var m = root.t
                        for(var i = 1; i < rep.index; i++)
                            m = m.times(root.t)
                        return m
                    }
                }
            ]
            NodeInstantiator {
                delegate: root.delegate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyEntity {
    t: Qt.matrix4x4(
           1, 0, 0, 0.1,
           0, 1, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 1
    )
    n: 5
    Entity {...}
}
```

Result:

qrc:/MyEntity.qml:26:17: Unable to assign Qt3DCore::Quick::Quick3DEntity to QQmlComponent

Comment: what and how do you assign to `root.delegate`? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `delegate` is the default property of `MyEntity`. In the second code block (usage) it is assigned in the last line (`Entity { ... }`). I can do it explicitly, i.e. `MyEntity { delegate: Entity { ... } }`, same thing.

Comment: It's unclear from your question but probably you assign Item (an instance) instead of component (a type).

Comment: @folibis the question is clear, minimal and reproducible: just paste my code into any Qt3D empty app, which I don't need to include here as it is overly long. Your guesses are wrong, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property declaration:

```
default property Entity delegate
```

must be changed to:

```
default property Component delegate
```

to work properly.